# I can display dynamic content in android activity but need to display it in pop up

Tags: android, layout, popupwindow

> MainActivity.java
>
> Displays generated no of views from the loop.
>
> My Code displays items generated based on the loop in an activity. I need it to be displayed in a pop up window.

```
package com.androidexample.dynamicallycreateelements;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dynamically_create_view_element);

        final LinearLayout lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearMain);

        // create the layout params that will be used to define how your
        // button will be displayed
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        //Create four
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {   
            // Create LinearLayout
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            // Create TextView
            TextView product = new TextView(this);
            product.setText(" Product"+j+"    ");
            ll.addView(product);

            // Create TextView
            TextView price = new TextView(this);
            price.setText("  $"+j+"     ");
            ll.addView(price);

            // Create Button
            final Button btn = new Button(this);
                // Give button an ID
                btn.setId(j+1);
                btn.setText("Add To Cart");
                // set the layoutParams on the button
                btn.setLayoutParams(params);

                final int index = j;
                // Set click listener for button
                btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Log.i("TAG", "index :" + index);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                "Clicked Button Index :" + index, 
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

               //Add button to LinearLayout
                ll.addView(btn);
               //Add button to LinearLayout defined in XML
                lm.addView(ll);  
        }
    }
}
```

> dynamically_create_view_element.xml
>
> layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FirstScreen" 
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="#898989"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="Shopping Cart" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearMain"
        >

     </LinearLayout>   


</LinearLayout>
```

> Screenshot of output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a Dialog. Android has some good documentation and examples here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html